# How to Invoke a .NET XML Web Service Using AFNetworking Library

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using the following code to invoke the http://www.highoncoding.com/Customers.asmx web service.

UPDATE 1:

Now, I have the following code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getAll 
{   
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://highoncoding.com/Customers.asmx?op=GetAll"];    

    NSString *soapBody = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>    <GetAll xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];
    [request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetAll" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation start];
```

But instead of returning XML it returns HTML/CSS.

UPDATE 2:

I was missing the httpMethod line:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Comment: You don't appear to be supplying a post body, but http://www.highoncoding.com/Customers.asmx?op=GetAll suggests one is required.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that the request ends up being Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; instead of what I have described above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` as headers.  Your SOAP XML string needs to be the post body of the request.

I'd recommend constructing this request using SOAPClient, HTTPClient or just raw curl before taking random stabs using AFNetworking.

Compare this raw request to the request being generated by AFNetworking to see where the differences lie using a proxy like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com).

**Update:  Here is an example of a raw request that works**

[image: HTTP Client issuing the SOAP Request manually]

And the response:

[image: Response]

Comment: I updated the answer in the original question. Also I am using a software called Eavesdrop to see the network traffic.

Comment: So, I have installed Charles but I am not sure how you got the above interface. I also installed the FireFox proxy add on and everything.

Comment: Charles will just inspect the traffic.  This request was done using [HTTP Client](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient/) (this used to be free, but now is available in the Mac App Store)

Comment: Yeah I am using eavesdrop which also inspect traffic for some reason the body soap envelope is never sent!

Comment: That's because you're using AFNetworking completely wrong.  You're setting the headers in the body and trying to use the xml string as a single unnamed parameter.  If you inspect the request this should be obvious.

Comment: Also, you aren't including the query string parameter.  I think that's required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13072/discussion-between-ben-scheirman-and-azamsharp)

Comment: Ah darnit I was missing the httpMethod attribute.